# Fast way to capture single images from Android-Camera

Tags: android, camera, image-capture

Since I could not find any useful documentation that shows how to get just single frames/images from camera I'm asking it here, may be somebody has a hint where to start.

I want to use single images from camera in a fast way. Means I want to retrieve a single image, then do some internal processing on it (which may need some time) and retrieve the next image as soon as this processing has beend one.

I found some examples/documents that describe retrieving of single images via an Intent that makes use of external applications - but that seems to be too slow for me. Beside of that some of these examples stored the image on disk where one would have to load it - which is way to slow too.

So how can I capture a single frame out of my own application so that the image is returned in memory using a format that can be used for further image processing? Examples I found here at stackoverflow.com and on other pages make use of camera App - that's not what I want.

Comment: @Siddharth Lele thanks for your heplful, friendly and exact answer - now I know how to implement it! Oh, sorry, it was the other guy who was able to give an answer, you just wasted my time.

Comment: And thanks for all the downvotes. Clearly you do not my purpose of being here on SO. You have 253 more questions for that. Don't forget them ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [Camera](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) class and call [takePicture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture%28android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback%29). Then you simply register a handler for [PictureCallback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PictureCallback.html).onPictureTaken.